# Insert Text to TextInput in Kivy using .kv File

Tags: python, kivy

Is there any way that you can insert text into a Text Input field similar to Tkinter `E1.insert()` (And also a way to clear text input fields)? I am trying to make a Board Foot Calculator app. My code is shown below for both .kv file and also the .py file.

Thank you so much! I appreciate it!

Python File Code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

Builder.load_file('design.kv')

answers = []

class CalcScreen(Screen):
    def list_view(self):
        self.manager.current = "list_screen"
    def calculate(self):
        LengthVal = float(self.ids.length.text)
        WidthVal = float(self.ids.width.text)
        ThicknessVal = float(self.ids.thickness.text)

        FinalCalc = LengthVal * WidthVal * ThicknessVal / 144
        FinalCalc = round(FinalCalc,2)
        answers.append(FinalCalc)

        # Insert text into TextInput

class ListScreen(Screen):
    def calc_view(self):
        self.manager.current = "calc_screen"

class RootWidget(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

## Kivy File Code:

```
<CalcScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            Label:
                text: "Board Foot Calculator"
            TextInput:
                id: length
                hint_text: "Length in Inches"
            TextInput:
                id: width
                hint_text: "Width in Inches"
            TextInput:
                id: thickness
                hint_text: "Thickness in Inches"
            Button:
                text: "Calculate"
                on_press: root.calculate()
            Button:
                text: "Clear"
            TextInput:
                id: board_feet
                hint_text: "Board Feet"
            Button:
                text: "List View"
                on_press: root.list_view()

<ListScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            Label:
                text: "Board Foot Calculator - List"
            TextInput:
                id: list
                hint_text: "List"
            TextInput:
                id: total_board_feet
                hint_text: "Total Board Feet"
            TextInput:
                id: total_boards
                hint_text: "Total Boards"
            Button:
                text: "Clear List"
            Button:
                text: "Back"
                on_press: root.calc_view()

<RootWidget>
    CalcScreen:
        name: "calc_screen"
    ListScreen:
        name: "list_screen"
```

Comment: I also just added the .kv code to the post.

Comment: You can use [insert_text()](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html#kivy.uix.textinput.TextInput.insert_text) to insert text. And you can clear the text using `ti.text = ''` (where `ti` is a `TextInput` instance).

Comment: Is that using the .kv file?

Comment: And also what do I need to put in the ()

Comment: No, that is not in the `kv` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `kv` file you can clear the `TextInputs` like this:

```
        Button:
            text: "Clear"
            on_release:
                length.text = ''
                width.text = ''
                thickness.text = ''
```

And you can set the text of the `board_feet` `TextInput` by modifying your `calculate()` method:

```
def calculate(self):
    LengthVal = float(self.ids.length.text)
    WidthVal = float(self.ids.width.text)
    ThicknessVal = float(self.ids.thickness.text)

    FinalCalc = LengthVal * WidthVal * ThicknessVal / 144
    FinalCalc = round(FinalCalc,2)
    answers.append(FinalCalc)

    self.ids.board_feet.text = str(FinalCalc)
```

Comment: Ok! That worked! But, is there a way to not erase the previous one and leave that there?

Comment: Just use `+=` instead of `=`.